# How to add custom classes to a Wordpress theme HTML tag?

Tags: customization

I've been googling how to add custom classes to the HTML tag of a Wordpress theme, but it's a tricky issue to research because all results are about HTML tags in general, not the **specific HTML tag** that opens a document. I want something like this:

```
<html class="custom-class">
```

I know the `body_class` filter can be used to customize the body's classes, but there seems to be no such thing for the html tag, yet Wordpress does output some classes for `<html>`, so they must be coming from somewhere...

Any ideas?

Comment: You just have to edit the theme file that has the tag. Probably header.php. There’s no filter or anything.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I figured so, but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no designated template tag for classes on `html` container.

For example in latest core Twenty Seventeen theme they are hardcoded:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
```

For proper customization you would likely need to create a child theme and override repsective template (likely `header.php`) or settle on manipulating classes with JavaScript.

Comment: Okay, I will find another solution then.